# Routing Error: uninitialized constant Sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, routes

I'm following [this Ruby Railcasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) to get some simple auth going, and I'm getting the error `uninitialized constant Sessions` when I navigate to the login page. I've checked my classes and the names are proper, which seems to be the problem most people report. Any idea what might be happening here?

The name of my controller file is `sessions_controller.rb` and the code is as follows:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Logged In!'
    else
      flash.now.alert = 'Invalid email or password'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Logged Out!'
  end
end
```

routes.rb file:

```
Albumtracker::Application.routes.draw do
  get "login" => "sessions/new", :as => "login"
  get "logout" => "sessions/destroy", :as => "logout"

  get "signup" => "users/new", :as => "sign_up"

  root :to => 'users#new'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  get "pages/index"
end
```

sessions/new view file:

```
<h1>Log in</h1>

<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <p>
  <%= label_tag :email %><br />
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= label_tag :password %><br />
  <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </p>
  <p class="button"><%= submit_tag "Log in" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Check the code in your sessions controller, or better yet, post some of it here so that others can see too.

Comment: Show `config/routes.rb` too please.

Comment: Can you show the sessions/new view too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have typos in your routes.  `/` should be `#` when specifying a controller and action.  Your routes should look like this:

```
get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"

get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
```

When you use `/` in your route the preceding portion is matched to a namespace.  So from `"sessions/new"` the router was trying to locate a controller named `Sessions::NewController`.  Since the namespace `Sessions` doesn't exist in your app, you got the uninitialized constant error.

Comment: Correct. It's a pretty usual beginner mistake.